# Pass data from one button to another in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

In my use case case I have a button which opens a modal and generates multiple buttons dynamically. Based on the `onclick` event from one of the button in the modal I will close the modal and update the page form values. So I will have to pass the JSON from modal to page form.

Here is my js code:

```
$('.package-div').on('click', '.get-package', function() {
    console.log("Inside get package button click field");
    var pageURL = $('#page_url').text();
    console.log("get package redirect url ", pageURL);
    $.getJSON("/getgitrepos/", function(data) {
        console.log("get git repos response data", data);
        console.log("get git repos name", data[0].name);
        var arrayLength = data.length;
        var repo1 = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            repo2 = "<div class=\"package-button-group\"><div class=\"col-md-6\"><label for=\"software\" class=\"control-label\"><p>"+data[i].name+"</label></div><div class=\"col-md-6 pull-right\"><p><input type=\"button\" class=\"add-btn-recommend-xs choose-package\" name=\""+data[i]+"\" value=\"choose\" onclick=\"return \""+data[i]+"\";\" /></div></div><br /><br />"
            var repo1 = repo1.concat(repo2);
        }
        $("#modalContent").html(repo1);
      });
});

$('#GetPackage').on('click', 'input', function() {
    console.log("Inside git choose button click");
    var packageObject = $(this).attr("onclick");
    alert ('button value' + packageObject + ' clicked');
    $("#title").val(packageObject.name);
    $("#url").val(packageObject.url);
});
```

I want set the title, url field from the data chosen in the modal button. Could someone help me on this?

Comment: store them in a global variable and pass it around.

Comment: "Global variables are evil." - Douglas Crockford

Comment: I notice you declared `var repo1` twice... Was that a typo?